# DrawingImage icon gets automatically trimmed when stretch=uniform

Tags: wpf, xaml

We use vector icons exported from Expression Design in our application, but I just noticed that all empty space in the icons gets trimmed away when they are displayed inside a stretched Image. Since the whole point of having vector icons is to allow them to stretch and scale nicely, this seems very strange.

Here is an example. Both the red and the blue star are designed in a 32 pixels wide document, but the blue star is much smaller. Setting the stretch property to Uniform suddenly makes the two icons the same size.

[image]

Is it possible to solve this and keep the whitespace around the icons? I guess a possible workaround would be to add a transparent background rectangle that covers the whole icon area, but this seems like a bad solution to me.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="GeneralTest.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DrawingImage x:Key="small_blue_star">
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Blue" Geometry="F1 M 20.4989,22C 20.4634,22.0177 16.2771,19.0022 16.2416,19.0022C 16.2061,19.0022 12.0021,22.0177 11.9844,22C 11.9489,21.9823 13.4921,17.0332 13.4744,16.9977C 13.4744,16.9623 9.4655,14.0354 9.48323,13.9999C 9.48323,13.9644 14.45,14.0177 14.4855,13.9999C 14.5032,13.9822 16.2061,8.99765 16.2416,8.99765C 16.2771,8.99765 17.9623,13.9822 17.98,13.9999C 18.0155,14.0177 22.9823,13.9644 23,13.9999C 23,14.0354 18.9911,16.9623 18.9911,16.9977C 18.9734,17.0332 20.5166,21.9823 20.4989,22 Z "/>
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>

        <DrawingImage x:Key="big_red_star">
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red" Geometry="F1 M 26.0781,32C 25.9941,32.0436 16.0823,24.6277 15.9983,24.6277C 15.9143,24.6277 5.96055,32.0436 5.91855,32C 5.83455,31.9564 9.48848,19.7856 9.44648,19.6983C 9.44648,19.6111 -0.0453207,12.4133 -0.00332647,12.326C -0.00332647,12.2388 11.7564,12.3697 11.8404,12.326C 11.8824,12.2824 15.9143,0.0243702 15.9983,0.0243702C 16.0823,0.0243702 20.0723,12.2824 20.1142,12.326C 20.1982,12.3697 31.958,12.2388 32,12.326C 32,12.4133 22.5082,19.6111 22.5082,19.6983C 22.4662,19.7856 26.1201,31.9564 26.0781,32 Z "/>
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Stretch=None" Width="100"/>        
                <Image Source="{StaticResource big_red_star}"    Width="32" Stretch="None"/>
                <Image Source="{StaticResource small_blue_star}" Width="32" Stretch="None"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Stretch=Uniform" Width="100"/> 
                <Image Source="{StaticResource big_red_star}"    Width="32" Stretch="Uniform" />
                <Image Source="{StaticResource small_blue_star}" Width="32" Stretch="Uniform"/>         
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I don't see your problem... if you don't want it to be stretched, then set `Stretch="None"` as in your first example. In your second example, you are telling it to stretch to fill the same dimensions as the larger star, so it *should* be that size. Also, I don't see any trimming (as your title says)... can you point it out?

Comment: Works as expected. The blue star is smaller than the red one because of its geometry data.

Comment: I would want the stretching to respect the whitespace that is part of the icon design. Scaling these star icons down to 16x16 pixels would make them equally big even though the blue star is (relatively) much smaller.

But if this is the expected result, I guess I will have to start adding transparent background rectangles to my icons.